# Silicon: conduction band minima

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, electronic-band-theory

Why do the energetic minima of the silicon conduction band lie not in a high-symmetry point like a $X$-point, but somewhere in $\Delta$-direction between points $\Gamma$ and $X$? What is the physical reason? Is it related to the spin-orbit interaction somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How atomic orbitals merge into crystal band structure is, well, complicated to capture in simple models.  As seen in, say, Ashcroft and Mermin (chapter 28), the energy surfaces for Si have symmetry along the <100> directions. In contrast, the surface for Ge have symmetry along the <111> directions, with the band minimum at the zone edge.  A comparison to the Fermi surfaces of various metals could be instructive - they can take on some seemingly odd shapes. Most of this can come from including enough atomic orbitals to mix together.

Now, for a more concrete example: Calzaferri and Rytz's paper on The Band Structure of Diamond (J. Phys. Chem 100 11122-11124 (1996)) models the band structure of diamond (very similar to Si, with the indirect gap out towards <100>). They show that they need to include the 3s atomic orbitals to get the conduction band correctly.

So, not so much 'spin-orbit', as you may need to take into account more atomic orbitals than you initially thought.